# Trying to use ts-nameof in Angular project via ts-patch

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using Angular 8.2 and installed [`ts-nameof`](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof#ts-nameof) 4.2.2 for my project and [`ts-patch`](https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch#ts-patch) 1.0.5 globally.

I ran `ts-patch install` and `ts-patch check` shows:

```
Checking TypeScript v3.5.3 installation in [...]
[+] tsc.js is patched with ts-patch version 1.0.5.
[+] tsserverlibrary.js is patched with ts-patch version 1.0.5.
[+] typescript.js is patched with ts-patch version 1.0.5.
[+] typescriptServices.js is patched with ts-patch version 1.0.5.
```

So I added the following from the [`ts-patch` examples](https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch#example-transformers) section to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      { "transform": "ts-nameof", "type": "raw" }
    ]
  }
}
```

and ran `ng serve -o`.

It's still complaining about `Cannot find name 'nameof'.`.

I don't see any additonal steps listed, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To fix compile time error `Cannot find name 'nameof'`

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": [..., "ts-nameof"]
  }
}
```

To fix runtime error `Uncaught ReferenceError: nameof is not defined`

```sh
# install ts-patch
yarn add -D ts-patch
ts-patch install
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "plugins": [
      {
        "transform": "ts-nameof",
        "type": "raw"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Tested with angular 10.1.6