# Angular: ts-nameof via ts-patch

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm trying to use https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof along with https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch. There are no errors during installation, but when compiling I get the error `Cannot find name 'nameof'`.

Has anyone used any library with nameof in Angular >= 8?

I need for enum (equivalent to Flags in C #):

```
export enum SimpleEnum {
    One = 1 << 0, // 1
    Two = 1 << 1, // 2
    Three = 1 << 2, // 4
}
```

do something like this:

```
const txt = nameof(SimpleEnum);
```

and receive

```
txt = "SimpleEnum"
```

Comment: A similar question was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937480/trying-to-use-ts-nameof-in-angular-project-via-ts-patch